# convert string into list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How can I convert this strip into list?

> [('WRB', 'PRP$'), ('PRP', 'VBD'), ('NN', 'CD'), ('VBD', 'PRP$'),
>   ('VBD', 'JJ'), ('VBN', 'RB'), ('PRP$', 'NN'), ('NNS', 'TO'), ('NNS',
>   'JJ'), ('IN', 'EX'), ('IN', 'CD'), ('VBP', 'RB'), ('RB', 'NNS'),
>   ('NNS', 'VBP'), ('JJ', 'IN'), ('NN', 'CC'), ('VBG', 'CC'), ('DT',
>   'IN'), ('VBP', 'WRB'), ('VBG', 'TO'), ('VBP', 'PRP$'), ('NN', 'JJ'),
>   ('VBG', 'PRP'), ('JJ', 'NNS'), ('PRP', 'VBP'), ('NN', 'VBG'), ('VBD',
>   'PRP'), ('PRP', 'DT'), ('CC', 'VBD'), ('JJ', 'JJ'), ('JJS', 'NN'),
>   ('IN', 'PRP$'), ('NNS', 'CC'), ('DT', 'NN'), ('CC', 'WRB'), ('VBN',
>   'JJ'), ('PRP', 'VBZ'), ('VBN', 'VB'), ('PRP', 'PRP'), ('JJ', 'VBN'),
>   ('IN', 'TO'), ('WP', 'NNS'), ('VB', 'CC'), ('VBP', 'DT'), ('VBN',
>   'DT'), ('PRP', 'CC'), ('NNS', 'JJ'), ('JJ', 'WRB'), ('CD', 'NN'),
>   ('RB', 'VB'), ('TO', 'RB'), ('WDT', 'NN'), ('VBP', 'JJ'), ('IN',
>   'NN'), ('WP', 'NN'), ('VBD', 'JJ'), ('PRP$', 'DT'), ('VBZ', 'DT'),
>   ('VBG', 'NNS'), ('CD', 'IN'), ('VBZ', 'RBR'), ('CC', 'JJ'), ('WDT',
>   'MD'), ('VBN', 'EX'), ('RB', 'VBP'), ('JJS', 'IN'), ('IN', 'EX'),
>   ('NN', 'IN'), ('CD', 'DT'), ('DT', 'VBD'), ('VBP', 'IN'), ('RB',
>   'MD'), ('VBN', 'PRP'), ('JJ', 'CC'), ('CD', 'PRP'), ('NN', 'JJ'),
>   ('NN', 'NN'), ('WDT', 'PRP'), ('VBP', 'VBG'), ('RB', 'TO'), ('VBZ',
>   'NN'), ('VBD', 'RP'), ('VBN', 'VBG'), ('WP', 'PRP'), ('NN', 'MD'),
>   ('VBP', 'VBN'), ('VBG', 'PRP$'), ('DT', 'VBN'), ('NN', 'VB'), ('VBZ',
>   'IN'), ('DT', 'CD'), ('DT', 'RBR'), ('VB', 'NN'), ('MD', 'RB'), ('TO',
>   'NNS'), ('VBD', 'DT'), ('RP', 'DT'), ('JJR', 'IN'), ('PRP', 'MD'),
>   ('DT', 'JJ'), ('PRP', 'VB'), ('NN', 'EX'), ('VBN', 'NN'), ('PRP$',
>   'JJ'), ('NN', 'WP'), ('CC', 'CD'), ('NN', 'JJR'), ('JJS', 'NNS'),
>   ('CD', 'VBG'), ('RP', 'PRP$'), ('DT', 'VBP'), ('NNS', 'NN'), ('EX',
>   'VBP'), ('JJS', 'PRP'), ('RBR', 'JJ'), ('RB', 'VBZ'), ('VBD', 'VBN'),
>   ('JJ', 'WP'), ('WRB', 'NN'), ('VBZ', 'RP'), ('VBD', 'NN'), ('VBN',
>   'CD'), ('NNS', 'CD'), ('CD', 'NNS'), ('DT', 'TO'), ('RB', 'NN'),
>   ('PRP', 'NN'), ('CC', 'NN'), ('VB', 'RP'), ('DT', 'VBZ'), ('VBZ',
>   'TO'), ('EX', 'VBZ')]

Any python command is available?

Comment: It looks like it's already a list. A string is usually surrounded by quote marks.

Comment: Its list . do u mean `convert tuple to list` ??

Comment: To all the downvoters, is it only because there were no outer quotes that you assume OP must have been mistaken in saying it's a string? Could have just copied from a file that's being read in, and pasted straight here on SO without going through Python. Quotes do not a list make.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input is a string of what you've presented, you probably want `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> s = """[('WRB', 'PRP$'), ('PRP', 'VBD'), ('NN', 'CD'), ('VBD', 'PRP$'), ('VBD', 'JJ'), ('VBN', 'RB'), ('PRP$', 'NN'), ('NNS', 'TO'), ('NNS', 'JJ'), ('IN', 'EX'), ('IN', 'CD'), ('VBP', 'RB'), ('RB', 'NNS'), ('NNS', 'VBP'), ('JJ', 'IN'), ('NN', 'CC'), ('VBG', 'CC'), ('DT', 'IN'), ('VBP', 'WRB'), ('VBG', 'TO'), ('VBP', 'PRP$'), ('NN', 'JJ'), ('VBG', 'PRP'), ('JJ', 'NNS'), ('PRP', 'VBP'), ('NN', 'VBG'), ('VBD', 'PRP'), ('PRP', 'DT'), ('CC', 'VBD'), ('JJ', 'JJ'), ('JJS', 'NN'), ('IN', 'PRP$'), ('NNS', 'CC'), ('DT', 'NN'), ('CC', 'WRB'), ('VBN', 'JJ'), ('PRP', 'VBZ'), ('VBN', 'VB'), ('PRP', 'PRP'), ('JJ', 'VBN'), ('IN', 'TO'), ('WP', 'NNS'), ('VB', 'CC'), ('VBP', 'DT'), ('VBN', 'DT'), ('PRP', 'CC'), ('NNS', 'JJ'), ('JJ', 'WRB'), ('CD', 'NN'), ('RB', 'VB'), ('TO', 'RB'), ('WDT', 'NN'), ('VBP', 'JJ'), ('IN', 'NN'), ('WP', 'NN'), ('VBD', 'JJ'), ('PRP$', 'DT'), ('VBZ', 'DT'), ('VBG', 'NNS'), ('CD', 'IN'), ('VBZ', 'RBR'), ('CC', 'JJ'), ('WDT', 'MD'), ('VBN', 'EX'), ('RB', 'VBP'), ('JJS', 'IN'), ('IN', 'EX'), ('NN', 'IN'), ('CD', 'DT'), ('DT', 'VBD'), ('VBP', 'IN'), ('RB', 'MD'), ('VBN', 'PRP'), ('JJ', 'CC'), ('CD', 'PRP'), ('NN', 'JJ'), ('NN', 'NN'), ('WDT', 'PRP'), ('VBP', 'VBG'), ('RB', 'TO'), ('VBZ', 'NN'), ('VBD', 'RP'), ('VBN', 'VBG'), ('WP', 'PRP'), ('NN', 'MD'), ('VBP', 'VBN'), ('VBG', 'PRP$'), ('DT', 'VBN'), ('NN', 'VB'), ('VBZ', 'IN'), ('DT', 'CD'), ('DT', 'RBR'), ('VB', 'NN'), ('MD', 'RB'), ('TO', 'NNS'), ('VBD', 'DT'), ('RP', 'DT'), ('JJR', 'IN'), ('PRP', 'MD'), ('DT', 'JJ'), ('PRP', 'VB'), ('NN', 'EX'), ('VBN', 'NN'), ('PRP$', 'JJ'), ('NN', 'WP'), ('CC', 'CD'), ('NN', 'JJR'), ('JJS', 'NNS'), ('CD', 'VBG'), ('RP', 'PRP$'), ('DT', 'VBP'), ('NNS', 'NN'), ('EX', 'VBP'), ('JJS', 'PRP'), ('RBR', 'JJ'), ('RB', 'VBZ'), ('VBD', 'VBN'), ('JJ', 'WP'), ('WRB', 'NN'), ('VBZ', 'RP'), ('VBD', 'NN'), ('VBN', 'CD'), ('NNS', 'CD'), ('CD', 'NNS'), ('DT', 'TO'), ('RB', 'NN'), ('PRP', 'NN'), ('CC', 'NN'), ('VB', 'RP'), ('DT', 'VBZ'), ('VBZ', 'TO'), ('EX', 'VBZ')]"""
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
[('WRB', 'PRP$'), ('PRP', 'VBD'), ('NN', 'CD'), ('VBD', 'PRP$'), ('VBD', 'JJ'), ('VBN', 'RB'), ('PRP$', 'NN'), ('NNS', 'TO'), ('NNS', 'JJ'), ('IN', 'EX'), ('IN', 'CD'), ('VBP', 'RB'), ('RB', 'NNS'), ('NNS', 'VBP'), ('JJ', 'IN'), ('NN', 'CC'), ('VBG', 'CC'), ('DT', 'IN'), ('VBP', 'WRB'), ('VBG', 'TO'), ('VBP', 'PRP$'), ('NN', 'JJ'), ('VBG', 'PRP'), ('JJ', 'NNS'), ('PRP', 'VBP'), ('NN', 'VBG'), ('VBD', 'PRP'), ('PRP', 'DT'), ('CC', 'VBD'), ('JJ', 'JJ'), ('JJS', 'NN'), ('IN', 'PRP$'), ('NNS', 'CC'), ('DT', 'NN'), ('CC', 'WRB'), ('VBN', 'JJ'), ('PRP', 'VBZ'), ('VBN', 'VB'), ('PRP', 'PRP'), ('JJ', 'VBN'), ('IN', 'TO'), ('WP', 'NNS'), ('VB', 'CC'), ('VBP', 'DT'), ('VBN', 'DT'), ('PRP', 'CC'), ('NNS', 'JJ'), ('JJ', 'WRB'), ('CD', 'NN'), ('RB', 'VB'), ('TO', 'RB'), ('WDT', 'NN'), ('VBP', 'JJ'), ('IN', 'NN'), ('WP', 'NN'), ('VBD', 'JJ'), ('PRP$', 'DT'), ('VBZ', 'DT'), ('VBG', 'NNS'), ('CD', 'IN'), ('VBZ', 'RBR'), ('CC', 'JJ'), ('WDT', 'MD'), ('VBN', 'EX'), ('RB', 'VBP'), ('JJS', 'IN'), ('IN', 'EX'), ('NN', 'IN'), ('CD', 'DT'), ('DT', 'VBD'), ('VBP', 'IN'), ('RB', 'MD'), ('VBN', 'PRP'), ('JJ', 'CC'), ('CD', 'PRP'), ('NN', 'JJ'), ('NN', 'NN'), ('WDT', 'PRP'), ('VBP', 'VBG'), ('RB', 'TO'), ('VBZ', 'NN'), ('VBD', 'RP'), ('VBN', 'VBG'), ('WP', 'PRP'), ('NN', 'MD'), ('VBP', 'VBN'), ('VBG', 'PRP$'), ('DT', 'VBN'), ('NN', 'VB'), ('VBZ', 'IN'), ('DT', 'CD'), ('DT', 'RBR'), ('VB', 'NN'), ('MD', 'RB'), ('TO', 'NNS'), ('VBD', 'DT'), ('RP', 'DT'), ('JJR', 'IN'), ('PRP', 'MD'), ('DT', 'JJ'), ('PRP', 'VB'), ('NN', 'EX'), ('VBN', 'NN'), ('PRP$', 'JJ'), ('NN', 'WP'), ('CC', 'CD'), ('NN', 'JJR'), ('JJS', 'NNS'), ('CD', 'VBG'), ('RP', 'PRP$'), ('DT', 'VBP'), ('NNS', 'NN'), ('EX', 'VBP'), ('JJS', 'PRP'), ('RBR', 'JJ'), ('RB', 'VBZ'), ('VBD', 'VBN'), ('JJ', 'WP'), ('WRB', 'NN'), ('VBZ', 'RP'), ('VBD', 'NN'), ('VBN', 'CD'), ('NNS', 'CD'), ('CD', 'NNS'), ('DT', 'TO'), ('RB', 'NN'), ('PRP', 'NN'), ('CC', 'NN'), ('VB', 'RP'), ('DT', 'VBZ'), ('VBZ', 'TO'), ('EX', 'VBZ')]
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded
>   string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may
>   only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings,
>   numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
>   expressions from untrusted sources without the need to parse the
>   values oneself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean flattening the input list?

```
lst = [('WRB', 'PRP$'), ('PRP', 'VBD'), ('NN', 'CD'), ('VBD', 'PRP$'), ('VBD', 'JJ'), ('VBN', 'RB'), ('PRP$', 'NN'), ('NNS', 'TO'), ('NNS', 'JJ'), ('IN', 'EX'), ('IN', 'CD'), ('VBP', 'RB'), ('RB', 'NNS'), ('NNS', 'VBP'), ('JJ', 'IN'), ('NN', 'CC'), ('VBG', 'CC'), ('DT', 'IN'), ('VBP', 'WRB'), ('VBG', 'TO'), ('VBP', 'PRP$'), ('NN', 'JJ'), ('VBG', 'PRP'), ('JJ', 'NNS'), ('PRP', 'VBP'), ('NN', 'VBG'), ('VBD', 'PRP'), ('PRP', 'DT'), ('CC', 'VBD'), ('JJ', 'JJ'), ('JJS', 'NN'), ('IN', 'PRP$'), ('NNS', 'CC'), ('DT', 'NN'), ('CC', 'WRB'), ('VBN', 'JJ'), ('PRP', 'VBZ'), ('VBN', 'VB'), ('PRP', 'PRP'), ('JJ', 'VBN'), ('IN', 'TO'), ('WP', 'NNS'), ('VB', 'CC'), ('VBP', 'DT'), ('VBN', 'DT'), ('PRP', 'CC'), ('NNS', 'JJ'), ('JJ', 'WRB'), ('CD', 'NN'), ('RB', 'VB'), ('TO', 'RB'), ('WDT', 'NN'), ('VBP', 'JJ'), ('IN', 'NN'), ('WP', 'NN'), ('VBD', 'JJ'), ('PRP$', 'DT'), ('VBZ', 'DT'), ('VBG', 'NNS'), ('CD', 'IN'), ('VBZ', 'RBR'), ('CC', 'JJ'), ('WDT', 'MD'), ('VBN', 'EX'), ('RB', 'VBP'), ('JJS', 'IN'), ('IN', 'EX'), ('NN', 'IN'), ('CD', 'DT'), ('DT', 'VBD'), ('VBP', 'IN'), ('RB', 'MD'), ('VBN', 'PRP'), ('JJ', 'CC'), ('CD', 'PRP'), ('NN', 'JJ'), ('NN', 'NN'), ('WDT', 'PRP'), ('VBP', 'VBG'), ('RB', 'TO'), ('VBZ', 'NN'), ('VBD', 'RP'), ('VBN', 'VBG'), ('WP', 'PRP'), ('NN', 'MD'), ('VBP', 'VBN'), ('VBG', 'PRP$'), ('DT', 'VBN'), ('NN', 'VB'), ('VBZ', 'IN'), ('DT', 'CD'), ('DT', 'RBR'), ('VB', 'NN'), ('MD', 'RB'), ('TO', 'NNS'), ('VBD', 'DT'), ('RP', 'DT'), ('JJR', 'IN'), ('PRP', 'MD'), ('DT', 'JJ'), ('PRP', 'VB'), ('NN', 'EX'), ('VBN', 'NN'), ('PRP$', 'JJ'), ('NN', 'WP'), ('CC', 'CD'), ('NN', 'JJR'), ('JJS', 'NNS'), ('CD', 'VBG'), ('RP', 'PRP$'), ('DT', 'VBP'), ('NNS', 'NN'), ('EX', 'VBP'), ('JJS', 'PRP'), ('RBR', 'JJ'), ('RB', 'VBZ'), ('VBD', 'VBN'), ('JJ', 'WP'), ('WRB', 'NN'), ('VBZ', 'RP'), ('VBD', 'NN'), ('VBN', 'CD'), ('NNS', 'CD'), ('CD', 'NNS'), ('DT', 'TO'), ('RB', 'NN'), ('PRP', 'NN'), ('CC', 'NN'), ('VB', 'RP'), ('DT', 'VBZ'), ('VBZ', 'TO'), ('EX', 'VBZ')]
output = [token for item in lst for token in item]
print output
```

Output:

```
['WRB', 'PRP$', 'PRP', 'VBD', 'NN', 'CD', 'VBD', 'PRP$', 'VBD', 'JJ', 'VBN', 'RB', 'PRP$', 'NN', 'NNS', 'TO', 'NNS', 'JJ', 'IN', 'EX', 'IN', 'CD', 'VBP', 'RB', 'RB', 'NNS', 'NNS', 'VBP', 'JJ', 'IN', 'NN', 'CC', 'VBG', 'CC', 'DT', 'IN', 'VBP', 'WRB', 'VBG', 'TO', 'VBP', 'PRP$', 'NN', 'JJ', 'VBG', 'PRP', 'JJ', 'NNS', 'PRP', 'VBP', 'NN', 'VBG', 'VBD', 'PRP', 'PRP', 'DT', 'CC', 'VBD', 'JJ', 'JJ', 'JJS', 'NN', 'IN', 'PRP$', 'NNS', 'CC', 'DT', 'NN', 'CC', 'WRB', 'VBN', 'JJ', 'PRP', 'VBZ', 'VBN', 'VB', 'PRP', 'PRP', 'JJ', 'VBN', 'IN', 'TO', 'WP', 'NNS', 'VB', 'CC', 'VBP', 'DT', 'VBN', 'DT', 'PRP', 'CC', 'NNS', 'JJ', 'JJ', 'WRB', 'CD', 'NN', 'RB', 'VB', 'TO', 'RB', 'WDT', 'NN', 'VBP', 'JJ', 'IN', 'NN', 'WP', 'NN', 'VBD', 'JJ', 'PRP$', 'DT', 'VBZ', 'DT', 'VBG', 'NNS', 'CD', 'IN', 'VBZ', 'RBR', 'CC', 'JJ', 'WDT', 'MD', 'VBN', 'EX', 'RB', 'VBP', 'JJS', 'IN', 'IN', 'EX', 'NN', 'IN', 'CD', 'DT', 'DT', 'VBD', 'VBP', 'IN', 'RB', 'MD', 'VBN', 'PRP', 'JJ', 'CC', 'CD', 'PRP', 'NN', 'JJ', 'NN', 'NN', 'WDT', 'PRP', 'VBP', 'VBG', 'RB', 'TO', 'VBZ', 'NN', 'VBD', 'RP', 'VBN', 'VBG', 'WP', 'PRP', 'NN', 'MD', 'VBP', 'VBN', 'VBG', 'PRP$', 'DT', 'VBN', 'NN', 'VB', 'VBZ', 'IN', 'DT', 'CD', 'DT', 'RBR', 'VB', 'NN', 'MD', 'RB', 'TO', 'NNS', 'VBD', 'DT', 'RP', 'DT', 'JJR', 'IN', 'PRP', 'MD', 'DT', 'JJ', 'PRP', 'VB', 'NN', 'EX', 'VBN', 'NN', 'PRP$', 'JJ', 'NN', 'WP', 'CC', 'CD', 'NN', 'JJR', 'JJS', 'NNS', 'CD', 'VBG', 'RP', 'PRP$', 'DT', 'VBP', 'NNS', 'NN', 'EX', 'VBP', 'JJS', 'PRP', 'RBR', 'JJ', 'RB', 'VBZ', 'VBD', 'VBN', 'JJ', 'WP', 'WRB', 'NN', 'VBZ', 'RP', 'VBD', 'NN', 'VBN', 'CD', 'NNS', 'CD', 'CD', 'NNS', 'DT', 'TO', 'RB', 'NN', 'PRP', 'NN', 'CC', 'NN', 'VB', 'RP', 'DT', 'VBZ', 'VBZ', 'TO', 'EX', 'VBZ']
```

Comment: Or just `itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst)`, which isn't much shorter.

Comment: no am reading that data from csv its of type string..i have checked that.so i need to convert tha actual data into list and i want this same result as its